# За что отвечает ip адрес мультикастовой группы?

Tags: c++, qt, udp

Собственно в чем вопрос - написал udp multicast чат на qt 5.9.5 c++

При запуске указывается адрес мультикастовой группы и порт. Сокет на чтение биндится на anyipv4, чтобы работал мультикаст

При одинаковых ip и порте все ожидаемо работает. При одинаковых ip, но разных портах, сообщения не приходят, что тоже ожидаемо. НО, при разных ip и одинаковых портах сообщения все равно продолжают приходить

Так происходит из - за того, что сокет на чтение биндится на любой ipv4? Вроде адрес мультикастовой группы должен работать как маска, которая фильтрует сообщения.